# Parsing text to create XML

Tags: c#, xml, regex, xml-serialization, text-parsing

I'm getting strings like this from HttpWebRequest:

```
Student■John■Smith
■Subject1■10■10
■■Exam■A■B■C
■■Questions■B■A■C
■Subject2■223■227
Student■Ala■Cat 
■Subject3■101■102
■■Exam■A■B
```

And I need to produce XML from it like this (to deserialize it to objects):

```
 <student name="John" surname="Smith">
   <Subject1>
   <degrees>
    <degree>10</degree>
    <degree>10</degree>
    <degree special="Exam">A</degree>
    <degree special="Exam">B</degree>
    <degree special="Exam">C</degree>
    <degree special="Questions">A</degree>
    <degree special="Questions">b</degree>
    <degree special="Questions">c</degree>
   </degrees>
   </Subject1>
   <Subject2>
   <degrees>
     <degree>10</degree>
     <degree>10</degree>
   </Student>
   <Student name="Ala" surname="Cat">
   <Subject3>
   <degrees>
    <degree>101</degree>
    <degree>102</degree>
    <degrre special="Exam">A</degree>
    <degree special="Exam">B</degree>
   </degrees>
   </Subject3>
 </student>
```

Is there any way to do this, other than using Regex? Or maybe there is another way to serialize it (original response) to objects?

Response model is:

```
Student ■ Student Name ■ Student Surname (*)
■ Class Name ■ Degree ■ Degree ■ Degree ... (*)
■■ Special Degree ■ Degree ■ Degree ■ Degree ... (*)

* - line can exist 0 or more time in a row
```

Comment: What are those "block" characters meant to be?

Comment: It would be nice to know what those black blocks actually are. Maybe use a Hex-viewer or some other tool?

Comment: Also, OP, do you really want the resulting XML to be malformed?

Comment: I assume they're tab characters as they are also used for indentation.

Comment: They are just "■" characters...

Comment: This has nothing really to do with HttpWebRequest does it - it is a simple text parsing question.

Comment: Although copy and past gives ascii value 166 (broken bar)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but your problem has nothing to do with HttpWebRequest.

Comment: Yeah... The title isn't correct... and question is more about text parsing... Can anybody change the title of question?

Comment: You might want to use `<Subject name="Subject1">` instead of `<Subject1>`, especially if "Subject1" can consist of multiple words and/or has other characters that are illegal as node name.

Comment: @Matthew: You should see an _edit_ link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to get you started, not a complete answer:

```
char sep = '■';  //whatever. copy/paste with care. 
XElement lastStudent = null, lastDegrees = null;

foreach (var line in lineCollection)
{
    string[] parts = line.Split(sep);

    int leading = parts.TakeWhile(s => s == "").Count();

    if (leading == 0)  // Student
    {
        // todo: validate parts.length, part[0]

        lastStudent = new XElement("Student",
            new XAttribute("name", parts[1]),
            new XAttribute("surname", parts[2]));

        doc.Root.Add(lastStudent);            
    }
    else if (leading == 1)  // Subject
    {
        // todo: validate 

        lastDegrees = new XElement("degrees",
                 parts.Skip(2).Select(p => new XElement("degree", p)) );

        lastStudent.Add(new XElement(parts[1], lastDegrees);               
    }
    else ...

}
```

Comment: Ok it works :D. But what if I want to change it to be like suggested by @HansKesting `<subject name="Subject1">` ?